# Can't connect to Azure postgres with psycopg. The server name you tried cannot be found

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, azure-sql-database, psycopg2

I want ot connect externally via psycopg2 to Azure postgresql. I have created a server with postgresql db on it.
The problem is that when I try to create a connection the error comes up saying that 'psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: The server name you tried cannot be found. Please use the correct name and retry. Please check your server name lfsserverlv.'

```py
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host='lfsserverlv.database.windows.net',
    dbname='lfsdb',
    user='adminlfs@lfsserverlv',
    password='some_password',
    sslmode='require'
)
```

The server name is on the screenshot below (Sorry for Russian in it)
There should be something else I pobably don't know on connections to Azure.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Try setting the port in the connection parameters. Default for Postgres is 5432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have passed the correct server name.

Get the connection information needed to connect to the Azure Database for PostgreSQL. You need the fully qualified server name and login credentials.

1. Log in to the **Azure portal**.
2. From the left-hand menu in Azure portal, click **All resources**, and then search for the server you have created (such as **chepra**).
3. Click the server name.
4. From the server's **Overview** panel, make a note of the **Server name** and **Server admin login name**. If you forget your password, you can also reset the password from this panel.

[image]

By using the above connection information, I'm able to connect Azure Database for PostgreSQL using python as follows:

[image]

For more details, refer "[Connect Azure Database for PostgreSQL using Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-python)".

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not working for me. Getting below error: Error: psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "xxx.postgres.database.azure.com" (xx.xx.xxx.xxx), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? Any help