# Getting connection timeout error while connecting Azure Postgres DB in Python

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2, connection-timeout, azure-postgresql

I am trying to connect Azure Postgres DB from Python using psycopg2 library but getting below error. Could someone help on this.

> Error: psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "xxx.postgres.database.azure.com" (xx.xx.xxx.xxx), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I referred below article from Microsoft but did not help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/connect-python

Referred this community post as well, but nothing worked. [Can't connect to Azure postgres with psycopg. The server name you tried cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56906027/cant-connect-to-azure-postgres-with-psycopg-the-server-name-you-tried-cannot-b)

Answer (score 2):

The connection timed out error is because the connection is blocked by server.

You need to enable the option "Allow public access from any Azure service within Azure to this server" by visiting to your server --> Networking option.
Do not forget to save the option.

This option configures the firewall to allow connections from IP addresses allocated to any Azure service or asset, including connections from the subscriptions of other customers.